# How can I output back slashes and double quotes in a Ruby string?

Tags: ruby, string

I'm trying to output

```
[fish] \"aquatic animal\"\n
```

But the closest I came is:

```
[fish]\aquatic animal

@entries.each do |key,value|
  puts "["+key+"]" +"\\"+value+"\n"
end

@entries = {"zebra"=>"African land animal with stripes", "fish"=>"aquatic animal", "apple"=>"fruit"}
```

Comment: Give us some input data, don't make us invent it ourselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### TL;DR

You can make this really short and easy to read using Ruby's [`sprintf`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf) and its handy partner [`%`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/String.html#method-i-25):

```
@entries = {"zebra"=>"African land animal with stripes", "fish"=>"aquatic animal", "apple"=>"fruit"}

template = '[%s] \"%s\"\n'

@entries.each do |key_and_value|
  puts template % key_and_value
end
# => [zebra] \"African land animal with stripes\"\n
#    [fish] \"aquatic animal\"\n
#    [apple] \"fruit\"\n
```

---

What you need to know is that inside double quotes, backslashes have special meaning. For example, in `"foo\nbar"`, `\n` is transformed into a newline:

```
puts "foo\nbar"
# => foo
#    bar
```

In order to use a literal backslash inside double quotes, it must be preceded by a backslash, which "escapes" it:

```
puts "foo\\nbar"
# => foo\nbar
```

To use double quotes inside double quotes, you need to escape them in the same way:

```
puts "I have "inner" quotes"
# => SyntaxError: unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting end-of-input
#    puts "I have "inner" quotes"
#                       ^

puts "I have \"inner\" quotes"
# => I have "inner" quotes
```

If we wanted to print `[fish] \"aquatic animal\"\n`, we'd have to do this:

```
puts "[fish] \\\"aquatic animal\\\"\\n"
# => [fish] \"aquatic animal\"\n
```

We replaced each `\` with `\\` and each `"` with `\"`, which looks pretty messy. On thing that will help is using Ruby's alternative "percent sign" syntax:

```
puts %{[fish] \\"aquatic animal\\"\\n}
# => [fish] \"aquatic animal\"\n
```

We still have to replace `\` with `\\`, because backslashes still need to be escaped using this syntax, but double quotes don't need to be escaped, so it's a little nicer. Putting it together, we get this:

```
puts %{[#{key}] \\"#{value}\\"\\n}
```

That's not bad, but it's still not especially easy to read. Another option is using `sprintf`, which lets us define a "template" string and then substitute values into it later on. Since we don't need interpolation (`#{...}`), we can use single quotes instead, which means we can use backslashes *and* double quotes inside it without escaping them:

```
template = '[%s] \"%s\"\n'
str = sprintf(template, "fish", "aquatic animal")
puts str
# => [fish] \"aquatic animal\"\n
```

As you can see, each `%s` in the "template" is replaced by one of the arguments to `sprintf`. Ruby also has a special shortcut for `sprintf`, which is the `%` operator:

```
str = template % [ "fish", "aquatic animal" ]
puts str
# => [fish] \"aquatic animal\"\n
```

We can combine this with your loop for an especially clean solution:

```
@entries = {"zebra"=>"African land animal with stripes", "fish"=>"aquatic animal", "apple"=>"fruit"}

template = '[%s] \"%s\"\n'
@entries.each do |key_and_value|
  puts template % key_and_value
end
# => [zebra] \"African land animal with stripes\"\n
#    [fish] \"aquatic animal\"\n
#    [apple] \"fruit\"\n
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
puts "["+key+"]" +" "+ "\\\""+value+"\\\"\\n"
```

Comment: Using `+` for string concatenation, at least to this extent, instead of using interpolation is unidiomatic in Ruby, and pretty hard to read.

Comment: It's also especially odd that you're using double quotes when you could use single quotes and eliminate five of the backslashes in your code.

Comment: Alternates: `puts "[#{key}] \\\"#{value}\\\"\\n"` or `puts '[' + key + ']' + ' ' + '\"' + value + '\"\n'`